# How do I count all letters in a column, alphabetically

Tags: sed, grep, columns

How can I count all letters in a column from "a" to "z" in a `.tsv` file with an output telling me how often each letter appears?

For example lets say this is a column

```
abc
abd
aabf
```

The output I want would be something like:

```
4 a 
3 b
1 c
1 d
1 f
```

Comment: Do you have `freq`? It is designed for this.

Comment: its actually for a uni assignment and the tasspecifys that we re just allowed to use the commands sed, uniq, sort, grep and more and cut. There are more colums in the actual exercise, this is just an exampleof where i got stuck. I guess my sytem has freq but if possible i should just use the given tools i guess

Comment: OK. that makes it clearer. Are the column number and input file(s) given as parameters?

Comment: IlluminaTea, please [edit] your example with a sample file with more than a single column. What should happen if the column has non `[a-z]` characters? Should they be ignored or counted too? Also, we usually ask for users attempts, especially when the question is an assignment. Please consider these points. Cheers!

Comment: @ icarus the coulmn number is given, its column nuber 7 in the file and idk exactly what you mean with input files.

Comment: @ quasimodo Characters that dont appear in the column schould not be counted i think, but if they would be counted as 0 that would not be a problem

Comment: im in my first semester btw and normally i would ask such questions my teachers/classmates in person but thx to corona I dont know anybody cause the complete semster is helt in homeoffice

Comment: Please add that information in your question. It should not be buried down in the comments that you want column number 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `grep`, `sort` and `uniq`:

```
$ grep -o '[a-z]' file | sort | uniq -c
      4 a
      3 b
      1 c
      1 d
      1 f
```

You could remove the leading spaces with `sed`:

```
$ grep -o '[a-z]' file | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *//'
4 a
3 b
1 c
1 d
1 f
```

Prepend `cut` if you only need the 7th column:

```
cut -f7 file | grep -o '[a-z]' | sort | uniq -c | sed 's/^ *//'
```

Comment: uhh that worked for me ty, ty very much and sorry to all others who misunderstood my question thought i asked a simple as possible by not giving to much information, wont do it like this again

Comment: @IlluminaTea Your problem is solved, but your question still lacks clarity. Please, edit your question addressing all the issues pointed in the comments. SE is also meant for helping other people that might have a problem like yours. But if the problem is undefined, it will not be helpful for anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Using only [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) basic tools + `csvcut`:

```
csvcut -c 7 file | tr -d '\n' | fold -w1 | sort | uniq -c
```

### Output

```
  4 a
  3 b
  1 c
  1 d
  1 f
```

Answer (score 0):

A [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) one-liner to the rescue (no pipe, only one process):

```
perl -0ane '
    map { $h{$_}++ } sort grep { /\w/ } split //, $F[6];
    print "$h{$_} $_\n" for sort keys %h
' file
```

I love Perl for this kind of ultra concise *pipe like* suit of chained calls.

The idea behind the hood, is to create a HASH (`$h`) and iterating over each characters and counting occurrences : `$h->{$_}++`

The hash before printed looks like:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => 4,
          'c' => 1,
          'f' => 1,
          'd' => 1,
          'b' => 3
        };
```

### Output

```
4 a
3 b
1 c
1 d
1 f
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the listed tools (cut, sed, sort, uniq) and nothing else apart from the shell

```
#!/bin/bash
column=$1
shift
cut -d'\t' -f$column  "$@" | 
    sed 's/[^a-z]//g;s/./&\n/g' | 
    grep . | sort | uniq -c
```

Use it as `myprog 7 file1 file2` to get the 7th column from the file1 file2.